SAS cannot read file cannot read properly the data
The imported data is full value,but in coding there,it will eat one character.Example that my data is RM800-RM1201,but the output just only RM800-RM120.The Data file format is xlsx
DATA WANT;
    SET WORK.IMPORT2;
    WHERE SHOEPURCHASEMETHOD = "Online";
RUN;


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Your question is not clear.  If your question is about reading data from an Excel file, please show the code that reads the Excel file. And please clarify the problem.  Is it that one character variable is being truncated?  You see the value "RM800-RM1201" in Excel but only see "RM800-RM120" in the SAS dataset?

Please check the actual character that looks like a hyphen.  If it is instead an endash or emdash and your XLSX file used single byte encoding and your SAS session uses UTF-8 then such a character will take more than one byte to store. So SAS might have guessed too short a length for the variable since the original string used fewer bytes.

You might have unicode characters in the XLSX data values which, in some situations, could cause a SAS session running with WLATIN1 encoding to truncate.

Are you saying that in WORK.IMPORT2 you can see all of the value.  But in WORK.WANT you cannot?  What encoding is you SAS session using? What encoding is WORK.IMPORT2 using?  What LENGTH is the variable in question?  What format does it have attached to it?  Are any of the characters in the values that appear truncated extended ASCII codes (values greater than 127 or '7F'x)?

Try setting
guessingrows=MAX;

in proc import.

Tq,but i have done

You need add more details on how and what you import.
